# Custom date format for inserting date in mysql database

Tags: vb.net

I have tried this code but the date format keeps staying the same when the record is entered

```
mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
mysqlconn.ConnectionString =

Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

Try
    mysqlconn.Open()
    Dim query As String
    query = "insert into jadco_test.adrv (id,type_adrv,date_discov,date_notif,pssd,psed,comment,hearing_date,sanction`enter code here`_sd,sanction_ed) values('" & Tbox_ID.Text & "','" & ComboBox_adrv.SelectedItem & "', '" & DateTimePicker_DD = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "','" & DateTimePicker_DN.CustomFormat & "','" & DateTimePicker_pssd.CustomFormat & "','" & DateTimePicker_psed.CustomFormat & "', '" & TextBox_comment.Text & "','" & DateTimePicker_HD.CustomFormat & "','" & DateTimePicker_SSD.CustomFormat & "','" & DateTimePicker_SED.CustomFormat & "' )"
    command = New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)
    reader = command.ExecuteReader

    MessageBox.Show("record saved")


    mysqlconn.Close()

Catch ex As MySqlException
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

Finally
    mysqlconn.Dispose()

End Try
```

Comment: 1) Avoid creating any queries by concatenating text - use parameters or [Moms will pwn your app](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: 2) When `INSERT`ing you should use `command.ExecuteNonQuery`, not `ExecuteReader`.

Comment: A DateTime is not a string. And when you store a value in a datetime column in your database you are not storing a string. How this date is represented by your database administration tool is not significant. Still a binary value representing a datetime is written and retrieved by your table. Then, when you display it to your users, you format it in the way you like. Finally follow the advice above about parameterizing your query

Comment: thank you for your reply , im actually new to mysql and vb . the data type is stored as date in the sql server

Comment: Make sure that you wrap your SqlConnection and SqlCommand in using statements.

Comment: what does that mean ?

Comment: It means you should stop and spend 30 minutes reading about the DB Provider objects you are trying to use. You should also read [ask] and take the [tour] to learn how the site works

Comment: `Using` is a way to ensure your objects are properly disposed. Just add `command.Dispose()` to your `Finally` block and you should be fine.

Comment: thanks for all the helpful comments guys , i had to change custom format in controller to yyyy-mm-dd